# Not sure if the DSL splitter is wired correctly

Tags: networking, modem, dsl, splitter, wiring

I read the yellow wire and black wire are irrelevant, and what matters is the green wire and black red wire.  There can only be 8 possible combinations but none works.  Is there anyone who can give me a hand?  I can log into the modem successfully but the modem is not letting me access the Internet.  On the surface of the modem, I see one red light, and two white lights, and for the modem to work properly, I must see three white lights.  The modem is called, Hub 3000

[image]

The DSL modem also gives me the error message, code 1000

Comment: Are you trying to connect a phone? If not, why are the "phone" wires hooked up? Also, where are the wires to your modem? They're not shown in the picture.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The "phoneline" cable that connects the DSL modem and the DSL splitter is on top of the photo

Comment: And just in case: I do not know what the situation in the US is like, but here in Europe many ISP's use the full spectrum for VDSL, and the phone works digitally via SIP. That means no DSL splitter is needed, and using a DSL splitter would cause your modem to not be able to connect to the internet. This may or may not apply to your US ISP.

Comment: You need to read the [manual for that splitter](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/761519/comtest-networks-cpe-01v-pots-splitter.html).  The wires should not be stripped (as you have done rather crudely).  You need to avoid untwisting the wire pairs (as you have done).  Note that the manual has a phone number & email address for assistance.  @dirkt -- your assumption that the OP is in the USA is incorrect; Comtest Networks is in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Red/Green/yellow/black are the incoming phone line, Green goes to Line T ("Tip"), and the Red goes to Line R ("Ring"). As previously stated, don't strip the wired, this side of the splitter, the connectors penetrate the wire insilation. I just re-located and re-wired mine.  The "phone" connections on this side of the splitter are for a wired telephone - normally not used.